# Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given?

Tags: php

Error Line

> Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
>   in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 70

Line 70

```
$result = mysql_query($con,"SELECT * FROM web_designnotes ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM web_designnotes ORDER BY id DESC");
```

Comment: How do you know its a mysqli connection ?

Comment: It's because it was receiving only one of them only.